# When I try to add a model to the world, this don't release, why?

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've installed Gazebo 1.3 from scratch.

But when I select a model, and  I try to add the model to the world, this don't work. The model don't release, this always be attached to the cursor. But I had read from http://gazebosim.org/user_guide/started_gui.html:

"To add a model to the world, left-click on the desired model in the Insert Tab, and move the cursor to the World View. The model should be attached to the cursor. Move it to the desired location and left-click again to release. You can then use the Translate and Rotate modes to orient the model more precisely."

Please, help me!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1415/when-i-try-to-add-a-model-to-the-world,-this-don%27t-release,-why?/) by [Jonatan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/218/jonatan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have taken a default model, for instance, the Coke Cake or the Bookshelf instead of using my model. I have also used the predefined shapes of the sphere, cube and cylinder. But it not working.

So I followed your instructions Daniel Vaz, but Gazebo from console gives no error. Anyway, thank you very much for your answer.

Does anybody has any idea?

PD: I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

---

Originally posted by [Jonatan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/218/jonatan/) with karma: 16 on 2013-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) on 2013-02-16**:
Do you compile gazebo from source or you used apt-get?

**Comment by [Jonatan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/218/jonatan/) on 2013-02-16**:
I have two Ubuntu's, both in virtual machines, but are the same. In one, I installed Gazebo 1.3.1 from sourse. On the other, I installed Gazebo 1.4 with apt-get. And in both I have the same error. Is there any difference?

**Comment by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) on 2013-02-16**:
Probably the problem is the virtual machine. Take a look: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25/run-gazebo-in-virtualbox/

**Comment by [Jonatan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/218/jonatan/) on 2013-02-22**:
Yeah!! that was the solution. thank you!!!